# MYSQL AutoCommit in shared environment

Tags: mysql, shared, autocommit

I am working on a server that is shared amongst many in my company.  There are multiple DBs on the server and I don't control the server.

The sys admins have set the defaults up with autocommit set to false.  This causes me trouble when trying to use PHPMYADMIN.

Can I safely set the autocommit to true without affecting other DBs on the server?  I assume yes, but the ramifications if I wrong could negatively affect other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) with

```
SET SESSION autocommit = 1;
```

so that it only affects your current connection, but this setting is not saved. Every time you reload or switch a site in PHPMyAdmin, this setting is reverted.

Setting it globally, which is the only other option, would change it for all users.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was worried about.